# Enter data from csv file to a website for search purposes

Tags: php, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to enter data from csv file to a search page. For example, I have a few companies entered such as IBM, Microsoft, Apple, Amazon, etc...However, if I have a csv file with many entries, is there a way to enter them all into a text field online?

I think python/php would be appropriate for this kind of task but I'm not entirely sure. Perhaps the community has suggestions on approach this problem?

CSV File

[image: csv]

Comment: You need to scrape the data and process it and enter it accordingly. Take a look at [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for scraping and the official python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library for entering data into a CSV file. Also [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html) might be useful.

Sidenote: I am pretty sure that scraping LinkedIn is illegal. They have sued people in the past for doing the same. Be careful.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that - if that's the case I'll avoid doing it, but I'd still like to know how to enter data into online text fields from CSV, so I'll take a look at some of your suggestions.